# Fetching JSON in PHP push from unspecified URL

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I am new to working with JSON in PHP. I want to help a friend on his software developed using PHP. There is payment integration which the interswitch requires URL where they can be posting JSON parameter upon every successful payment to help him keep track of the payment activities. The parameters are as follows

```
PaymentLogId    String
CustReference   String
Amount  Numeric
PaymentReference    String
IsReversal  Boolean
PaymentDate DateTime
BankName    String
CustomerName    String
ItemName    String
CustomerAddress String
```

The payment gateway insisted that he should write code that can capture the above JSON parameters and update his database.

I have:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);
echo $obj->firstname;

?>
```

But seems there should be address to fetch the information and they refused to give any address.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like they want to be able to post the resulting json to an API endpoint in your friend's server. Do they currently have an API architecture where this can occur? For instance they could have a route that accepts `POST` requests at `www.example.com/api/payments/` or any route. Your friend could then automatically handle the receipt of a successful payment in the controller that is associated with the server route.

Comment: Of course @Tom Con. But they don't have any API architecture I guess because they refused to give him any address but gave their server IP address. They want him to give them address like **www.example.com/capturepay** where they can be posting to

Comment: So your friend need to write a service to receive and manage the requests from the payment gateway company.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like they are expecting your friend to control a server endpoint and to be able to handle incoming `POST` requests. I don't see any other way around the issue.

Comment: Sure, but the problem is that how he can receive the JSON parameter in PHP

Answer (score 0):

The payment company needs an URL to POST data to your server. So you need to write a service to manage this requests.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html). Maybe it could help.